# How many trading voyages a year would this ship make?

Tags: ships, trade

How many voyages a year would a single trading ship make, usually?

Firstly, please let me know if I'm using the wrong terms for any part of this question. I suspect my answer is already out there somewhere, but I imagine I'm not asking the right question.

So, this is a fantasy small island (around 8000 square miles) with two main ports. It's the largest island of a set of islands, with a large hook landmass to the South and a cold, but sustainable larger landmass to the North. I reckon it will take around a month and a half to two months to do a trade run with some of the closer, larger land masses (with about a week in between to get the stuff off and on the boat).

I have a few options to make sure my dude is back and fore his home base (for example, using it as a stopover between the north and south, or trading along the other chain islands in closer proximity), but I'm not really sure how many times a year he'd make a journey on the same ship.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To be as clear as possible, is your boat moving between the two main ports? If so, where are the ports located one to another? How far apart are they? Also, we need to know what kind of boat is it about : a 16th's century sailboat, a modern and huge container ship...?

Comment: "The average sailboat can travel about **5 knots per hour** (a knot is 1.15 miles per hour). So, that means covering an average of about 120 miles per day. At that pace, you will arrive in Hawaii [10,931 mi², ~2,100 miles away from San Diego] in about 18 days."

Comment: How far apart,are the ports? Age of sail, steam, or ICE diesel?  Is the ship configured: break-bulk, bulk or container?

Answer (score 8):

Unless it's a scheduled bus run with cargo & provisions sorted at both ends then it's always open ended how long is spent in port. Regular scheduled runs usually are a day or less in port as everything is ready for them when they arrive.

Otherwise cargo needs to be sold, and cargo and food etc,. needs to be acquired for the return. Both of these can take a lot of time and effort. Time is rarely a problem until under way with perishable goods. Ships can and do travel one leg just with ballast, but that doesn't fit your scenario since you seem to want two way trade.

If you show up in port and need to sell your cargo in one day, then expect to get fleeced. If you need to buy your cargo in one day you can expect to get fleeced even worse. If sufficient supplies are not stockpiled already or are problematic you need to wait. So you don't constrain the port time on lengthy voyages. Your 2 month voyage and a week stopover each end seems fine to me.

Ships make all their money tied to dock. Nothing while sailing. The solution to more time making money is to decrease sailing time, not dock time. Dock time is also for the benefit of your sailors. These are skilled workers, you need to keep them happy unless you're using slaves. A week or more is a reasonable period to have them out in shifts making merry with their pay. 2 or three weeks would be better if you have a big crew.

Comment: Why would you put ballast in the ship?

Comment: @Daron if you sail empty you need ballast, cargo ships aren't designed to sail empty.

Comment: I think the fundamental difference between this answer and Monty Wild's is how the trade is organised: you are assuming am independent trader, who must negotiate each sale and purchase while present in port. Monty Wild's description is more of a *delivery service*, shipping goods at pre-arranged prices, and turning around as many such deliveries as possible. I suspect both have historical precedent in different time periods and contexts - e.g. independent traders vs trading companies with established ["factories"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(trading_post)).

Comment: @IMSoP I covered that in the first sentence. But the other answer doesn't account for sailors needs and other fundamentals associated with even bus run voyages.

Comment: I'd never heard the term "bus run", so didn't really know what that sentence meant.

Comment: A lot of time, trade is done - potentially multiple times - *whilst* the cargo is in transit. This is one of the jobs of ship brokers. Also, a lot of the time, unsold cargo may be delivered and prices negotiated by different merchants at the port. There are many different trade scenarios that apply. I think this answer is focusing on the traders and ship crew overlapping significantly which no doubt also happens, but the setup is going to vary depending on many factors

Comment: @NeilSlater fair points. I'm thinking of a fantasy setting without things like the internet to communicate mid voyage etc,. OP doesn't say, but the length of the voyage suggests it. Modern container ships are pretty fast

Comment: Shipbrokers predate the internet by a long, long margin. The lack of communication made things uncertain, but like today, people were willing to invest in uncertain ventures.

Comment: Yeah, Monty's answer basically describes how a "liner" sort of service works, with fixed routes and set rates (think Maersk if you want a modern day example with actual ships) vs. this answer, which basically describes the tramp trade

Comment: One should also note that a sailing boat needs maintenance. If the boat encounted any major storm on the last sailing leg it will stay in harbour for a few weeks to get everything fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Ships make no money tied to a dock.  They sail as quickly as they can between their ports of call, spend the minimum possible time in port, usually just enough to unload goods, and load goods for the next voyage, plus supplies, do any necessary maintenance and set off as soon as possible.

A sailor on such a ship would likely spend most of his time on the ship, since he would only be paid for the time he has spent working.  If he took leave, it might be until the next time the ship was in port.

As to how many voyages per year, just calculate how many the ship *could* make, and that's how many its owners will try to *get* it to make.

The answer above is assuming that the owners of the ship will have pre-arranged cargoes and shipping routes, and the captain and crew need only travel between the pre-determined ports and load and unload as necessary.

However, if a ship was a tramp freighter, matters would be different.  Tramp freighters operate on commission, going wherever they are needed with whatever cargoes their crew (often the [purser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purser)) can find.  For such a ship, more time may be spent in port while the purser advertises for cargoes and follows up advertisements for cargoes requiring a ship, or a cargo purchased for transport to a destination at which it might be sold.

During this time, the ship would be resupplied, maintained, and some crew might take leave.

However, once a cargo had been found and a destination determined, the ship would be loaded as quickly as possible, and would proceed to its destination as quickly as was safely possible.

Again, the less time that is spent in securing a cargo and the less time is spent travelling to its destination, the more money the ship may make.

Comment: Ah brilliant. Thank you. I was worried that there should have been a specific turnaround time/ allowed time in port before the next sailing. This is very useful; especially so as I can begin to see why I may not have found the answer I was looking for by ye-olde-google search alone.

Comment: The only caveat to this I can imagine is if certain seasons are too risky to sail in (weather, pirates, etc), but then the ship would go ply the trade routes *somewhere else* for that time period

Answer (score 1):

> How many voyages a year would a single trading ship make, usually?

Regarding your exact question:
Whether the destination port knows when to expect the ship to arrive can affect which of the two great answers below are the better answer for your story.

I think you should decide if there is a means of communication between the ports other than the ships themselves. (Carrier pigeon maybe?)

The two great answers above are **independent trader** (also called wildcat in modern vernacular) and **delivery service** (also called a *scheduled bus run* above).  One would be the best for your world, but I don't have enough information about what you want your story to be/achieve.

Related to your question:
I'd recommend further thought about how important shipping is to the story.
If the purpose of the question is to only answer the question 'how many round trips' then measure the distance between the points and use 5-6 mph (8-10 kmh) to get the travel time.  Subtract one round trip per year (if you want) because bad wind has more impact than good wind. Draw out a map of your islands and put arrows between them that indicate the travel time and you're done.
This is sometimes called "hand-waving" and there's nothing wrong with it if your story doesn't focus on the specifics of sailing. Your question's main character is a sailor, but how much does your story focus on sailing?

If this is a love story between the sailor and someone, then maybe you should do lots of hand waiving.

If part purpose/plot of the story is to immerse your reader in the sailing aspect of the story, they you'd want to think about which of the below you would want to address about the 'real word' aspects of sailing:

1. Is there bad weather?

For example, is there a hurricane season where ships must be in port.
Or if no ports are safe in a hurricane, what does that look like?
My brother had a Spring Break job in college where he and some friends were flown to the Northeastern United States in early March, then they would sail a nice sailboat to the Carribean for its rich owner. The owner would fly down and use it during the Summer, and then someone else would sail it back up to the NE in August (before hurricanes were expected) where it would remain for the winter.  This is intended as a real-world example to help your thought process about hurricane type bad weather, and what people do today to avoid/account for it.

2. Do you want to bring in boat maintenance? (Mentioned by @quarague & @Montey Wild)

All boats need maintenance.
Even a modern fiberglass hull boat, that isn't in an accident, needs regular maintenance/replacement for its fittings - and your story has wooden boats which in addition to fittings and sail maintenance, need regular tar and pitch maintenance on the hull to avoid leaking.  All ocean boats also need treatment for barnacles that attach to the hull and slow the boat down by creating drag.  (barnacles grow into the hull, decreasing its structural integrity over time)

3. What about human aspects of the sailors, such as length of shore leave?  (Mentioned by @kilisi)

You mentioned your dude being on the "same ship" - so maybe all your boats have a quick turnaround time, but most sailors want more time in port and are willing to sail on the next ship?

4. Ballast  (Mentioned by @kilisi)

Expanding: You cannot sail a cargo ship without a certain amount of weight in them (cargo + ballast) because they are *designed to carry* a lot of weight.
They are too unstable without it - they ride to high in the water and would likely capsize (tip over) without carrying the minimum weight they are designed to carry.

Answer (score 0):

**Depends on the winds.**

Most sailing ships with multiple masts [work best](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sail) if the wind comes from the side and behind, not directly behind. A single sail may work best with the wind from directly behind. In either case, wind coming from directly ahead is *bad.*

So if you want a round trip, either you need a change of wind directions between the two parts of the trip, or you cannot sail the most direct course.

- The more modern the sail rig is, the better the ship will be at [tacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacking_(sailing)), that is moving both upwind *and* sideways. This will give much slower effective speeds than regular sailing.
- Find some sort of circle route, where each leg has dependable winds. Google [trade winds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_winds). Your world might have a pattern fundamentally similar to Earth, or perhaps you have a different number of [Hadley cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadley_cell). (Fantasy sailors would not understand the cause, they just note the effects.)
- Large ocean currents like the Gulfstream might help or hinder progress.
- Finally, traders might have to wait for seasonal changes.

So in the worst case, you get one roundtrip per year. Sail one way in the most favorable season for that direction, sail the other way in the most favorable season for the other direction.

In a somewhat better case, one direction usually goes smoothly, but the other direction means tacking and even waits while adverse winds lock the ship in a bay or harbor. Say three weeks one way, three months the other way, total four months per roundtrip.

In the best case, you get something like the east-west Atlantic crossing. Quick crossing both ways, but the landfall is not where you want but rather where the winds take you, and then the ship has to sail north or east to get to the new starting point. (This is also a good match for navigators who can do latitude but not longitude, see [chronometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#The_chronometer)).

Comment: Even a single mast works best in broad reach.

Comment: @user58697, depends on the details of the rig and hull.

Comment: Bermuda cut, of course.